# Form helper in codeigniter autoescapes form data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-form-helper

I've got the following code: `echo form_submit('Update Info', icon('accept') . ' Update Info', 'class="button medium green"');`, which outputs a styled submit button. The `icon` function returns the image embed code to the proper icon. Unfortunately it seems that the `form_submit` method escapes the `<>` in the image embed code.

How can I tell CI to trust the data from this and leave it untouched?

Update: From the CI docs:

> Note: If you use any of the form helper functions listed in this page
>   the form values will be prepped automatically, so there is no need to
>   call this function. Use it only if you are creating your own form
>   elements.

Anybody know how to disable this semi-annoying feature for one output?

Comment: A quick look in the source code says nothing about this. You'd better stick to plain HTML here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_submit` gives you a `<input type='submit'>` style button. The `value=""` field in `<input>` does not allow you to use HTML in it, so its not CI escaping, its your browser.

In order to use `<input type='submit'>` submit buttons with HTML, you'd better use `<button type='submit'>Your text with HTML here</button>`, but you have to write the HTML by yourself.

**Update**. It is escaped. HTML helper source code. Shouldn't just be looking at forms. Oh well, but the solution above still applies.